# Get Page Title In Master Page Code Behind

Tags: c#, title, master-pages

I want to get the page title in c# master page code behind.

I tried using `Page.Header.Title;` property but it return `null`.

Please help me to get the title.

Thanks in advance.

Shibin V.M

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your page head include `runat="server"` then you can easily get the Page title by

```
string Title = Page.Title;
```

EDIT:

Using the Title property of Page requires a header control on the page. (e.g. `<head runat="server" />`).

Answer (score 4):

You can set the page title on Page_Load Event like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 { Page.Title = "Page Title"; }
```

and get the page title using

```
string title = Page.Title;
```

Answer (score 2):

try this in your master page

```
string Title = "Your Site: " + this.Page.Title;
```

Answer (score 2):

Set `Title` attribute of content pages `<%@ Page Title="Contact us" ../>` and handle the Master page's Load or Init event to get `Page.Title` or `Page.Header.Title`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your html tag, it has worked for me `<%: Page.Title %>`.
For eg: `<li class="active"><%: Page.Title %></li>`.