# Dynamically set master page body title

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Similar to the question below, I am trying to grab the Title entered in the title tag in each page and use that to update an asp label to dynamically set the title on each page. I am trying only use the c# code on the master page, yet only empty strings are being returned by page.title when each page has a title such as:

```
<title>Graphs</title>
```

[Get Page Title In Master Page Code Behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178243/get-page-title-in-master-page-code-behind)

```
public partial class MasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      string TempTitle = Page.Title;
        title.Text = TempTitle;
    }
}
```

Ok it seems 'Page.Title;' doesn't grab the text between the title tags, does anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was the asp title was empty as shown below

```
<%@ Page Title=""
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make any sense to code in master page if you want to get title of each page in c#. Just use this code on each page.

```
string S = this.Page.Title;
YourLabel.Text = S;
```

Comment: Ok but now I would have to copy and paste that onto 20 pages rather than 1 if using the master page